# Android Access is denied when building

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've recently switched over my project to Kotlin and went through all the precompiled errors I found. I then went to build the project and I'm receiving this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Work\knew-tek\Knew_Tek\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\0\META-INF\LICENSE
>   (Access is denied)

I am using `Android Studio 3.0` which really new, but from what I can tell this shouldn't happen. I've drilled down into the file structure and have confirmed that the folder does exist. The only exception is that the LICENSE folder is lowercase instead of upper. I don't believe this should affect anything, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just exclude it from packaging. Add this to your module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    ...
}
```